# Как оптимизировать функцию экранирующую специальные символы в строке?

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

```
function addSlashes(str) {
    str = str.replace(/\[/g, '\\[');
    str = str.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\');
    str = str.replace(/\^/g, '\\^');
    str = str.replace(/\$/g, '\\$');
    str = str.replace(/\|/g, '\\|');
    str = str.replace(/\?/g, '\\?');
    str = str.replace(/\*/g, '\\*');
    str = str.replace(/\+/g, '\\+');
    str = str.replace(/\./g, '\\.');
    str = str.replace(/\(/g, '\\(');
    str = str.replace(/\)/g, '\\)');
    return str;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3561493/1016033

Comment: @AlexeyTen Сделай ответом - поставлю галку.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Да просто ссылку ответом сделай и всё. Ссылка тоже может быть ответом. Почему нет? Не обязательно креатив генерировать.

Comment: Всё уже решено в английской версии. http://stackoverflow.com/q/3561493/1016033

Comment: я был уверен, что добавил ответ 

Comment: @AlexeyTen, Khipster ссылка не может быть ответом, об этом прямо сказано [в справке](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: @AlexeyTen Имеется ввиду "всего лишь ссылка" а не любая ссылка. Т.к. ответ состоящий из одной лишь ссылки может быть не понятен. Ссылка же с пояснением наоборот является отличным ответом. Порой я поражаюсь тому как технари толкуют правила ХD

Comment: @Khipster я не толкую правила, я пытаюсь донести до вас их суть. Ответ должен быть самодостаточен, чтобы будущие посетители могли использовать его напрямую. Ссылка может быть лишь дополнением к ответу. Все просто. Код `RegExp.escape` **прямо в ответе** + ссылка - это ответ. Просто ссылка с "вот тут отличное решение!" - не ответ.

Comment: @PashaPash Мне дали ответ, я считаю его отличным, но приходит ПашаПаша и объясняет мне что я так не должен так считать, т.к. он считает по другому. :D Откуда взялась "самодостаточность ответа" никому не известно. Более того копировать чужие ответы прямо запрещено правилами: "являются точными дубликатами других ответов;" и это разумно, ведь для этого и придумали ссылки когда то :)))

Comment: @Khipster Запрещено копировать чужие ответы *в рамках сайта*. По той простой причине, что вместо этого вопрос, в который вы хотите скопипастить ответ, нужно закрыть как дубликат. Вы можете считать ответ ссылку отличным. От этого он не начнет соответствовать правилам. Я, как модератор, *обязан* его удалить, и, по возможности донести до автора ответа причину удаления. Если вас это не устраивает - вы всегда можете [высказаться на мете](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @PashaPash В итоге согласно вашей логике: невозможно ни скопировать, ни дать ссылку на другой ответ на этом же сайте. :)

Comment: @Khipster английский stackoverflow - это другой сайт. с него спокойно можно копировать :)

Comment: @PashaPash добавил новый ответ с функцией

Comment: @AlexeyTen спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё уже решено в английской версии: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711/1016033

```
RegExp.escape = function(s) {
    return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно собрать все в одно выражение и в качестве замены указать номер группы

```js
function addSlashes(str) {
  return str.replace(/(\[|\\|\^|\$|\||\?|\*|\+|\.|\(|\))/g, '\\$1');
}

console.log(addSlashes('.*'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function addSlashes(str) {
  // Сливаем все регулярки в одну
  // Сохраняем спец. символ в группу и экранируем его
  return str.replace(/(\[|\\|\^|\$|\||\?|\*|\+|\.|\(|\))/g, "\\$1");
}

console.info(addSlashes('some[\\T^Q$I|K?H*N+B.P()]'));
```