# Экранировать кавычки

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Проблемы с регулярными выражениями.
Здравствуйте как в тексте реплейсом экранировать (менять все `"` на `\"`)

и как поменять все `\` на `\\\` (тройное)

спасибо!

Comment: почему именно тройное?

Comment: так надо передать текст

Comment: Вероятно, это дубликат для https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/545191/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5

Comment: @Visman только там ответ не очень.

Comment: Viseman согласен

Answer (score 0):

```
function(s) {
    return s.replace(/["\\]/g, '\\$&');
};
```